# Edges for Collapsible tree D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having some issues with the edges for the collapsible tree in D3.  I have tried swapping the x and y positions and was able to move the nodes but not the edges?  I tried to swap the x0 and y0 but still not working?

```
      // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

http://jsfiddle.net/6FkBd/383/
```

Comment: Do you want it top to down or left to right?

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis  Top Down, sorry didnt specify.

Comment: Got it! http://jsfiddle.net/6FkBd/383/ needed to change diagonal function...

Answer (score 0):

You had to change this values of x and y too.
Check this one out http://jsfiddle.net/6FkBd/394/ 
`var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });`

By the way, I think we both working on same thing, I am trying to create OrgChart that will support collapsing/expanding. But not being lucky yet.